# Trigger completely separate div based on hover of other div

Tags: javascript, css, hover, overlay

Is it possible to trigger changes to CSS of an element that is completely unrelated to the hovered div?

I have a CSS hover effect on a dropdown menu, that I also want to trigger the opacity of a div right at the bottom of the page to create a background overlay effect.

This is the CSS I'm using:

```
#overlay {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position:absolute;
    top:120px;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
    height:120%;
    width:100%;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
}
#menu-main-menu li.menu-parent-item:hover ul.sub-menu,
#menu-main-menu li.menu-parent-item:hover #overlay {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
}
```

The hover of the sub menu works fine, but the div #overlay is right at the bottom of the page, and doesn't get called when it's hovered.

I've tried all kinds of alternatives such as :hover > #overlay, :hover + #overlay, but nothing seems to trigger it. I also can't seem to find a definitive answer to the question.

Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot achieve this using CSS, if you do not have to use a CSS only solution then javascript is your best friend.

Comment: Please post your HTML, so we can actually see if it's possible in this case.

Comment: @LuudJacobs It's hard to enter HTML, as this is a wordpress menu, so contains lots of code. using `*` as the css selector after the submenu, but the overlay disappears whenever I hover over margin of any child elements. (like submenus)

Comment: Unless the overlay div and the target div share a common parent AND the overlay div comes after the target element then there is no CSS selector that will do this for you.

Comment: The only parent they share is body, and it does come after the menu.. not directly after, but it is after.

Comment: Is the menu the only thing in `#menu-main-menu`?  And you want the overlay displayed whenever they're interacting with the menu?

Comment: The menu is #menu-main-menu

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can load this style in a php file and then use jQuery to apply the css when your div has been hovered on.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to select parent element in css and that means that you cannot move up in hierarchy.

```
<ul class="hover-parent">
    <li></li>
</ul>
<div>Something here</div>
<div class="target"></div>
```

From this point : 
`.hover-parent li:hover` you cannot go up (to ul or div).

Selectors which you tried to use are "next":

A>B - This will select only direct B children of A

A+B This will select B immediately preceded by A

Here you can find W3C documentation of CSS selector
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

And demos:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Notice that it will be really confusing for user that different part off app/page is changing when he is hovering something else. Bad UX idea.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use JavaScript to do this.

Your posted selector `#menu-main-menu li.menu-parent-item:hover #overlay` is looking for `#overlay` somewhere inside of an ancestor element of `li.menu-parent-item` that is somewhere inside of an ancestor element with an id of `#menu-main-menu`.

Using the child selector `>` will not work as the overlay element is not a child of the list element you're hovering in your menu from what you have described and from comment responses.

As *@Paulie_D* has pointed out the two target elements, the element to be hovered and the overlay element, need to adjacent siblings to use the sibling selector `+`. From what you have described and the comment responses they are not adjacent siblings.

I have setup a basic example for you using jQuery. This example displays the overlay as long as you are hovering any element in the `.main-menu` element.

**HTML**

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item Three</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item Four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item Five</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<main>
    Content here.
</main>
<footer>
    <div class="overlay">This is my overlay.</div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
    margin: 25px auto;
    width: 500px;
}
ul,
li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
main {
    min-height: 300px;
}
footer,
.overlay {
    height: 50px;
}
footer {
    position: realative;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.main-menu {
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
}
.main-menu > li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.main-menu > li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    width: 150px;
}
.overlay {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**jQuery**

```js
$overlay = $('.overlay');
$('.main-menu > li').hover(
    // when hovered
    function() {
        $overlay.css('display','block');
    },
    // when NOT hovered
    function() {
        $overlay.css('display','none');
    }
);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ednf2pzq/

**Edit**

You could simplify the jQuery hover selector to `.main-menu`.

**jQuery**

```js
$('.main-menu > li').hover(
     // same code as before
);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ednf2pzq/1/

Comment: This looks good, although it's not making any changes to the overlay div when I apply it to my site. In my example I'm using `#menu-main-menu > li` as the hover line, and the overlay is also using an ID. Would this affect it at all? By the way, #menu-main-menu is the ID of the initial ul of the whole menu.

Comment: Yes, you would have to configure things to your own needs. So the jQuery selector would be `$('#menu-main-menu > li').hover(...)` or simply `$('#menu-main-menu').hover(...)` and and instead of `$('.overlay')` use `$('#overlay')`.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did, and it doesn't make the overlay display at all. I'll come back to it, and will let you know.

Comment: There could easily be other elements and CSS that might effect the display of your overlay. Without seeing the current working HTML/CSS it's hard to rule out or see if that is the issue. Do you know how to use developer tools in Chrome, Firefox etc.?

Comment: Yeah I do, I'll come back to it when I'm next looking at the menu.

Comment: Cool, I would make sure that you can see the CSS `display` property switching on `#overlay` and go from there. If you do see it switching when hovering your menu then you know the jQuery is working and that the issue is most likely other CSS or even the CSS of `#overlay` that is causing a display issue. Otherwise refine the jQuery selector.